# Tuples from string by regular expressions in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have string like `{param1=foo}{param2=bar}hello world!`
I need to extract array of tuples **(paramName, value)** from this string and get something like `[(param1, foo), (param2, bar)]`

Is it possible in Scala to extract this tuples by only one regex? Because I managed to do this only in way like

```scala
val str = "{param1=foo}{param2=bar}hello world!"
val param = """(?<=\{)(.+?)(?=\})""".r // extract everything between { and }
val keyValue = """(.+)=(.+)""".r // for extracting key and value
val parameters = for (keyValue(key,value) <- param.findAllIn(str).toArray) 
                     yield (key,value)
```

And it doesn't look sweet.

Also I tried to use

```scala
val param = """(?<=\{)(.+?)=(.+?)(?=\})""".r
```

But it return `param=value` as one string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an expression that will find things like `{A=B}` where `A` and `B` do not contain `{`, `}`, or `=`.

```
scala> val Re = """\{([^{}=]+)=([^{}=]+)\}""".r

scala> val Re(a,b) = "{param1=foo}"
a: String = param1
b: String = foo
```

And if you want to find all matches in a string:

```
scala> val s = "{param1=foo}{param2=bar}hello world!"

scala> Re.findAllIn(s).matchData.map(_.subgroups).toList
res9: List[List[String]] = List(List(param1, foo), List(param2, bar))
```

Comment: Yeah! This is the droids I'm, looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Without regex you can do:

```
scala> val str = "{param1=foo}{param2=bar}hello world!"

scala> str split '}' filter(x => x.head =='{' && x.contains('=')) map{x => val Array(key, value) = x.tail split '='; key -> value }
res9: Array[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] = Array((param1,foo), (param2,bar))
```

Or in a clearer way:

```
// We find different blocks
val str1 = str split '}'

// We remove invalid blocks (end of the String in your case)
val str2 = str1 filter(x => x.head == '{' && x.contains('='))

// We transform the String into a tupple, removing the head
val str3 = str2 map{x => 
  val Array(key, value) = x.tail split '='
  key -> value
}
```

Comment: Very nice:) but instead imperative-like taking element by index, you can do pattern matching `val Array(key, value) = x.tail split "="; key -> value`.

Comment: Indeed that's better, I didn't know the `key -> value` equivalent.

Comment: please don't use parenthesis and curly brackets in one expression. This looks ugly. `str2 map { x => ... }` is completely enough.

Comment: Definitely, posting an answer can learn a lot. Thanks for the advice, I edited my answer accordingly.